# Why I am getting error in 'date' data type?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am creating a table inserting reminders of my reminder application but while creating the table `insert_reminder` I am getting error for the `DATE` column. I tried to figure out if I had written any keyword wrong or not but everything was right.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE set_reminder(
    -> SID int(10) primary key auto_increment,
    -> UID int(10) references registration(UID) not null,
    -> "DATE" date not null,
    -> SUBJECT varchar(10) not null,
    -> DESCRIPTION varchar(100) not null,
    -> CONTACT varchar(60) not null,
    -> RECUR_NEXT int(2));
```

This is the table I am tring to create.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'not null,
"DATE" date not null,
SUBJECT varchar(10) not null,
DESCRIPTION varcha' at line 3
```

And this is the error I am getting.

Comment: In MySQL reserved words are enclosed in backticks (`), not double quotes.

Comment: Also you need to put `not null` before `references`, not after i.e. `UID int(10)  not null references registration(UID),`

Comment: @Nick I had tried with backticks but was getting the same error

Comment: See my second comment - I hadn't seen the whole error message. That's why you have your current error. But if you fix that it will complain about the `"DATE"`

Comment: ok I got it. It's working fine now.

Comment: glad to hear it!